# add a category to all products that already have a common category

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I would like to add a category with jquery to woocommerce all products with class "tax_qeeboo", starting from a specific day, but I can't understand where I'm wrong

```
var startpromozioneuno = new Date("November 30, 2021 00:00:00")
  if(today.getTime()>startpromozioneuno.getTime()){
    $('body.tax_qeeboo').addClass('tax_occasioni');
  }
```

The Category appeears in the code, but doesn't appears in the frontend.
The final result I would like to obtain is as if I had added a category from the woocommerce panel

thanks

Comment: Its unclear what you want to achive here. You want to add additional class in body if specific class exsists? Or you want to update all products with specific category to have another one saved in the database ?

Comment: Sorry! The second:  i want to update all products that have class ".tax_qeeboo" with specific category to have another one saved in the database

Comment: Okay then go to your Admin dashboard go to products -> categories. Then next to each category you will see a number showing how many products that category have. Click on it and will list all products with this category. Then select all products and do a bulk edit and select the category you want to add. If its multiple pages just go each page or increase products per page but that may need more time to update depends on your server etc. Before that make a backup ofc :)

Comment: I try to bulk edit in that way but doesn't works: there is something in backend that block that function . I try to use BEAR plugin, but for the change that i need i must buy the premium version.  For this reason i am trying to do something with jquery :(

Comment: You cant update database just with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following function in your theme functions.php

**Make backup before using.**
Change $taxonomy , $post_type , $filter_term_id , $target_term_id with your params.

```
add_action('init','update_post_taxonomy_terms');
function update_post_taxonomy_terms() {

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // Taxonomy we are looking for
    $post_type = 'product'; // Post type we are looking for
    $filter_term_id = 199; // The taxonomy term id we are looking for 
    $target_term_id = 263; // Term id we want to add

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $filter_term_id
            )
        )
    );

    $results = new WP_Query($args); // We need all posts that we will update
    $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $results->posts, 'ID' ); // We need only post ids
    
    error_log(print_r($post_ids,true)); // Check the post ids that will be updated if all good uncomment rest of the code

    //Uncomment when ready
    // foreach($post_ids as $post_id):
    //     wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $target_term_id, $taxonomy );
    // endforeach;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!